# Crud com MongoDB e C# erro no tipo ou namespace

Tags: c#, mongodb, namespace

Acompanhando um tutorial do Macoratti [aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/15/11/crud_mongo1.htm), aparece erros em três tipos. Não sei o que acrescentar para resolver. Fiz um Copiar e Colar e deu erro. Abaixo o código:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Mvc_MongoDB.Models
{
    public class PaisDB
    {
        public MongoDatabase Database;
        public String DataBaseName = "PaisDB";
        string conexaoMongoDB = "";

        public PaisDB()
        {

            conexaoMongoDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexaoMongoDB"].ConnectionString;
            var cliente = new MongoClient(conexaoMongoDB);
            var server = cliente.GetServer();

            Database = server.GetDatabase(DataBaseName);
        }

        public MongoCollection<Pais> Paises
        {
            get
            {
                var Paises = Database.GetCollection<Pais>("Paises");
                return Paises;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Erro aqui: **MongoDatabase** => Tipo ou Namespace não pode ser encontrado

Erro aqui: **GetServer** => MongoClient não contem uma definição para GetServer

Erro aqui: **MongoCollection** => Tipo ou Namespace não pode ser encontrado

Como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu caro, isso pode mudar conforme a versão do driver do mongoDb mas sugiro sempre baixar a versão mais atual. As modificações que vou sugerir aqui foram obtidas da [Documentação Oficial da MongoDb](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/getting_started/quick_tour/)

Sobre os problemas relatados fiz as seguintes modificações:

**MongoDatabase :** Altere para `IMongoDatabase`

**GetServer :** Retire essa função e obtenha diretamente a instancia do DB

**MongoCollection :** Altere para IMongoCollection

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Mvc_MongoDB.Models
{
public class PaisDB
{
    public IMongoDatabase Database;
    public String DataBaseName = "PaisDB";
    string conexaoMongoDB = "";

    public PaisDB()
    {

        conexaoMongoDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexaoMongoDB"].ConnectionString;
        var cliente = new MongoClient(conexaoMongoDB);
        Database = cliente.GetDatabase(DataBaseName);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<Pais> Paises
    {
        get
        {
            var Paises = Database.GetCollection<Pais>("Paises");
            return Paises;
        }
    }
}
}
```